# strtotime and then convert to UNIX?

Tags: php, strtotime, unix-timestamp

**EDIT**

Per the comment below, here's my attempt at splitting / combining / converting the string prior to implementing mktime...

```
$date1 = explode("T",'2005-03-27T00:00:00');
$date2 = explode("-", $date1[0]);
$try = mktime($time1,$time2,0,$date2[1],$date[2],$date[3]);
print $try;
```

### // Prints out: 951793200

**Original Question:**

I've inherited a database and would like very much to convert the bizarre way the data is stored to something more mysql-friendly...

In the meantime, I get a *text* string (yes... text)... That I'd like to convert to unixtime...

So, I'll get a string that looks like this:

> 2005-03-27T00:00:00 03:00 AM

I'd like to convert it to:

> 1111885200

Dates and times always mess me up... I've done a number of things using strtotime and mktime, but can't get it formatted the way I want.

Comment: what is the problem with `strtotime`  ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html should be relevant

Comment: What does the T00:00:00 part mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is how I would do it.

```
$ex = '2005-03-27T00:00:00 03:00 AM';
$format = '%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00 %H:%M %p';
$strf = strptime($ex, $format);
$date_str = $strf['tm_mon'] + 1 . '/' . $strf['tm_mday'] . '/' . ($strf['tm_year'] + 1900) . ' ' . $strf['tm_hour'] . ':' . $strf['tm_min'] . ':00';
echo $date_str;
echo "\n";
echo strtotime($date_str);
echo "\n";
echo date('m-d-Y H:i:s', 1111885200);
```

But, your desired result does not seem to be correct based on the date you posted.

**OUTPUT**

```
3/27/2005 3:0:00
1111921200
03-26-2005 17:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a litte converter script that does the task for you.

Please check the optional parameters of [mktime](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.mktime.php)

You could try to split your string in  hour / minute / second / month / day / year and put that into mktime. Then mktime will give you the unix timestamp for that.

Comment: I tried something like that actually... My first problem is that it yielded unexpected results... My second problem was that I'd have to first convert times to 24-hour format, and what I tried, failed... (i.e., if the time is 11:00 PM, for example... I'll edit my original post to show my latest and greatest and unsuccessful attempt...

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not a fan of regular expressions unless absolutely necessary, but they might be necessary here to pick out the time zone piece.

```
preg_match("/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})(T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}) (AM|PM)/", '2005-03-27T00:00:00 03:00 AM',$matches);
```

Will give you $matches that look something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2005-03-27T00:00:00 03:00 AM
    [1] => 2005
    [2] => 03
    [3] => 27
    [4] => T00:00:00
    [5] => 03:00
    [6] => AM
)
```

I would feed those pieces into a [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object. Then you can output it into any [format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) you want. You also may have to adjust that regex some so it can handle all your dates.

Answer (score 0):

If the T00:00:00 part is useless, just remove it and use [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/strtotime):

```
<?php
$date = '2005-03-27T00:00:00 03:00 AM';
$timestamp = strtotime(preg_replace('!T[^ ]+!', '', $date));

var_dump(date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $timestamp));
?>
```

This prints:

```
string(19) "27/03/2005 03:00:00"
```